# Excel VBA code to cut from one cell and paste in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to set up a code in Excel using VBA to copy cells greater than "0" from column "H" and paste the contents to the cell in column "G". For instance, if "H2" is greater than "0" then cut and paste into "G2", and so on. I can't seem to find anything that will work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use the [Macro Recorder](http://www.contextures.com/excel-macro-record-test.html).  Record a simple cut/paste macro, then modify it with an IF() statement.  Good luck, you can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you along some, in order to copy paste using VBA look at the following:

```
Sub Copy_paste()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
End Sub
```

It should be pretty straight forward but whatever is placed in "A1" is the source to copy from, and whatever is placed in "B1" is the destination. By the way to **cut** instead of **copy**, just replace .Copy with .Cut instead.

As far as your logic of greater than and such, just add some logical operators around the copy / paste method I showed above. For example to copy A1 to B1 if A1 is greater than 2:

```
Sub Copy_paste()
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") > 2 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**

Also please note that you can reference a cell in many different ways. The following are all synonymous if everything is happening within the same workbook:

- ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
- Range("'Sheet1'!A1")
- ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)
- Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)
- Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Comment: That was very nice of you, Eric.

Comment: @Bandersnatch Thanks! I go back and forth sometimes of whether to make new people do the research themselves or to give them just enough to learn, even if I may not get any rep from it

Comment: Me too, and I think you struck a good balance. He'll need to add code to loop through the column, and the start you gave him may get him there.  @Dean, comment back here if you run into problems with that part.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess the problem I was running into was the looping. I'm trying to set up a macro that will allow me to go through the worksheet checking all of column H for anything greater than "0" and cutting and pasting into column G. For some reason when I try to create one it comes up with errors. I've tried everything but looping.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess the problem I was running into was the looping. I'm trying to set up a macro that will allow me to go through the worksheet checking all of column H for anything greater than "0" and cutting and pasting into column G. For some reason when I try to create one it comes up with errors. My problem is that the worksheets are different every time and the range changes. One week it might be H1:H25 and the next week H1:H32. So, I am looking for something that will cover variable ranges. The code you sent me will help and maybe I can figure out the rest as I play with it.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the help. I'm still a bit of a noob with coding but I am trying to learn as I go.

Comment: @DeanFahe In order to loop use the ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1) version of referencing a cell. where the values after Cells refer to the column and row.

Comment: @DeanFahe Your question never mentions looping at all. My answer does answer your question as is. If you find my answer helpful then please vote it up one and if you feel it answers the question you actually asked then please click the check box to accept it. If you have a different question from your original then by all means post a new question on SU. I (and nobody) won't keep answering questions on top of questions unfortunately (not trying to be rude)

Comment: @Eric F, I apologize. I've skimmed the forums but have never posted anything. I appreciate your help and will use your advice. I believe the answers you gave were exactly what I needed. I will make sure and vote your answer up as soon as I am able to. I guess I'm still too low of a level to vote.

Comment: @DeanFahe While you can't vote, you can accept at any reputation.

Comment: @DeanFahe Thanks for accepting. Now if you have a question about looping.. first try what I taught you here and then if you get stuck ask a specific question as to where you got stuck as a new question. You got many -1 votes because your original question came off more of as "write this for me" and not a specific question

Comment: @Eric F Got it. Once again, thanks for your help,